# UICollectionView does not recognize tap on cell anymore when tapped during scrolling?

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uigesturerecognizer, uitapgesturerecognizer

A `UICollectionView` is presented and without scrolling a touch on one of its cells is recognized immediately in `collectionView(_:didSelectItemAtIndexPath:)`.

However when scrolling the `UICollectionView` and tapping a cell to stop the scroll movement, subsequent taps on the cell are not recognized anymore and `collectionView(_:didSelectItemAtIndexPath:)` is not triggered.

Only when scrolling stops by itself without a tap subsequent taps are recognized.

I already set

```
collectionView.delaysContentTouches = false
collectionView.canCancelContentTouches = false
```

and

```
override func gestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
    return true
}
```

Side notes:

- The cell contains an `UIImageView` subview as full cover.
- The `UICollectionView` is inside a `UITabelViewCell` that is inside a `UIScrollView`, however for both I have set `scrollEnabled = false` and `canCancelContentTouches = false`.

The same behaviour occurs when setting `collectionView.allowsSelection = false` and adding a UITapeGestureRecognizer to the cell.

Why are taps on cells not recognized?

**Update**: Another strange effect is that when the `UICollectionView` is scrolled to the area outside of its content so that it would bounce back it does not bounce but stops the scrolling and halts the view when a cell is tapped quickly after releasing the pan. In that state no taps are recognized, so this is basically the same behaviour as described above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for this behaviour was that the collection view is inside the view of a view controller which was presented with (simplified, never mind the forced unwrapping):

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().windows.last?.makeKeyAndVisible()
let parentViewController = UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow!.rootViewController
parentViewController.presentViewController(self, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

The solution was to remove the whole first line `makeKeyAndVisible`.